# Does SQL-Lite Database for android support key constraints

Tags: android, sqlite

Can we create relationships between tables in android sql lite database.

Comment: This was not helpful: http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html?  This seems definitive: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html.  What was wrong with this document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since API Level 8 (Froyo).

Comment: Foreign key constraints were only added in SQLite version 3.6.19, and API Level 8 (Froyo) was the first Android platform to use a recent enough version of SQLite. See http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html